# Definitive length of primitive C and Fortran types

Tags: c, compiler-construction, 64-bit, fortran

I am currently revamping the native bindings for BLAS/LAPACK (Fortran libraries) for all major OS on 32/64 bit as a Java library: [netlib-java](https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java/).

However, I've started to hit some problems to do with data type differences between the UNIX/Windows world, and between Fortran / C.

Tables of [Fortran](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialMixingFortranAndC.html) and [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) data types are pretty non-commital because sizes [are not explicitly defined by the C language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575).

**Is there a canonical source (or can we create one by referencing authoritative sources?) of all the bit sizes IN PRACTICE of the primitive data types on major OSes for both Fortran and C?**

Or, at the very least, the Fortran types in terms of the C types.

i.e. populate a table with the following columns (with a few to begin):

```
OS      ARCH    Language Type             Bits
Linux   x86_64  C        int              32
Linux   x86_64  C        long             64
Linux   x86_64  C        float            32
Linux   x86_64  C        double           64
Linux   x86_64  Fortran  LOGICAL          32
Linux   x86_64  Fortran  INTEGER          32
Linux   x86_64  Fortran  REAL             32
Linux   x86_64  Fortran  DOUBLE PRECISION 64
Linux   x86_64  Java JNI jint             32
Windows x86_64  Fortran  INTEGER          32
Windows x86_64  Java JNI jint             64
...
```

(I'm not sure if this is correct)

It is possible to lookup the Java types in terms of C primitives in the `jni_md.h` which is shipped with every JDK.

Comment: Like the C standard the Fortran standards do not define the size, in bits, of the language's intrinsic data types.  But then the Fortran standards scarcely recognise the existence of bits at all.  Good luck with your efforts but I think that you are missing an important element in the equations, the compiler (version) used.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark gcc/dragonegg for all (initially), but I'm sure someone will want to use Intel compilers at some point.

Comment: Normally stuff like that is covered under mixed language programming for the compilers.  For instance, in Silverfrost, it is under mixed language programming/data types/basic data types.  On the old ps4 (and probably DVF, CVF and IVF) compiler, it is under Programmer's guide/Programming with Mixed Languages.  Can't believe that Windows INTEGERS are 16 bits or is that a trick to make sure we're reading everything.  Ha Ha.

Comment: @cup I'm not 100% sure about this, but I know I'm getting compiler warnings when I try to pass `jint` (which is typed `long`) to the CBLAS methods that are defined with Fortran `INTEGER`.

Comment: whoever downvoted this, are you going to tell us why?

Comment: You could always force it with INTEGER*4 or INTEGER*8 or using the kind= notation.  That takes the guesswork out.  Similarly with reals though I'm not sure how common REAL*12 or REAL*16 are.

Comment: @cup my code is all in C interfacing with either C wrappers over the Fortran or directly accessing the Fortran methods (sometimes without a C header file, eek!). I have a suspicion the differing JNI types are causing more problems than the Fortran/C types, which have *got* to be similar, right?

Comment: You can always check your jni.h to find out what they are set to.  On mine, jint is 32 bits and jlong is 64, jfloat is 32 and jdouble is 64.  You may have to track it into jni_md.h for the particular environment.

Comment: @cup as noted in the question, it's actually in `jni_md.h` :-P It's the Fortran/C conversions I'm really after.

Comment: If you're using the later versions of Fortran, they have the ISO_C_BINDINGS, which, in theory, should get the right size.  This is very vendor dependent.  eg IVF+MSC might be very different from gcc/gfortran on Windows.

Comment: ISO_C_BINDING is helpful to tell a Fortran program what Fortran kind maps to particular C kinds, but it isn't going to help another language, such as Java, figure out what these are.

Comment: @SteveLionel I'm working on the level of JNI, so C/Fortran translation is all I need.

Comment: @cup please post your reference to [ISO_C_BINDING](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ISO_005fC_005fBINDING.html) and I will accept it as the answer... it is **exactly** what I was after (for the GNUniverse, at least).

Comment: @cup oh hold on, how come there are multiple (incompatible) C types that map to the same Fortran type?? Like `int32_t` and `int64_t`?

Comment: There is no universal ISO_C_BINDING and all these will tell you is the KIND numbers for that particular Fortran implementation that correspond to selected types in the "companion" C implementation. Don't make the mistaken assumption that KIND numbers are byte sizes. Sometimes they are, sometimes they aren't - implementation dependent.

Comment: Fortran integer ISO_C_BINDING `kind=C_INT` will be the same as a C `int`, but that doesn't tell you how many bytes those types are.  If you use `kind=C_INT32_T` matching C type `int32_t`, you will have a 32 byte integer in both Fortran and C.   But knowing this doesn't magically tell you the sizes of variables declared in Fortran source code declared simply as `integer` and `real`.  If you want this control, you either need to rewrite the Fortran source code or write glue interface routines whose declaration uses the specific types, then calls the library code.

Comment: the Fortran to C mappings are enough... I'm waiting for @cup to answer this so I can mark his solution as the definitive answer.

Comment: Another approach is a configure step that analyzes the BLAS/LAPACK library or the Fortran compiler to determine the types that they use.

Comment: @M.S.B. I now know that the types are identical, so no further analysis is needed. i.e. the CBLAS/LAPACKE signatures are correct because of ISO_C_BINDING

Comment: @fommil: I don't know why you think that ISO_C_BINDING provides you that guarantee about the types, since, as far as I can tell, LAPACK doesn't use it.

Comment: It doesn't just depend on the operating system. If you have a 16-bit C compiler and a 32-bit C compiler it depends on which compiler you're talking about.

Comment: @fommil: I won't be posting a reference for ISO_C_BINDING because I normally just work off the include files which are provided by the compilers.  As Steve Lionel says, there is no universal ISO_C_BINDING.

Comment: @M.S.B. yes BLAS/LAPACK does use it implicitly.

Comment: @cup well whatever you want to write then... please just upgrade it to an answer so I can mark it and close this off.

Comment: I don't know what implicitly using the ISO_C_BINDING means.  The ISO_C_BINDING is in effect if the Fortran source code contains `use ::  iso_c_binding` and its kinds are used in the relevant declarations.  Otherwise it isn't in effect.

Comment: @M.S.B. the BLAS/LAPACK are exposed in C through CBLAS and LAPACKE... looking at the API will show you that it is using the "sensible" mapping. That's all I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by @cup in the comments, there is an [ISO_C_BINDING](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ISO_005fC_005fBINDING.html) standard. That gives us a level of comfort (at least with GCC) that the mappings as noted in the CBLAS/LAPACKE C API (which uses basic C types) are portable across architectures with that compiler. As noted in the question, this is about bit sizes **in practice**, not some abstract concept of what the languages guarantee. i.e.

- `REAL` -> `float`
- `DOUBLE PRECISION` -> `double`
- `INTEGER` -> `int`
- `LOGICAL` -> `int`

and then it's up to C to define the byte sizes of the primitive types and up to the `jni_md.h` to define the Java primitive types.

**In practice**, this means that the only disconnect is that on 64 bit Windows `long` is 32 bit (64 bit on 64 bit Linux) and `jint` is defined in terms of `long`. Therefore the [compiler complains about `jint*`/`int` type conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300653) during Windows builds that can be safely ignored.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your approach.

1. It's not necessarily the operating system that defines these lengths; the compiler can do so as well in some cases.
2. The user can also change the default lengths in some circumstances. For instance, many Fortran compilers have an "r8" option that causes the default size of real to be 8 bytes (for gfortran, "-fdefault-real-8").
3. BLAS/LAPACK are supposed to work for single and double IEEE precision, regardless of the default size of data types on a given system. So the Fortran interfaces should always use 4 byte reals and 8 byte doubles, regardless of the system you're working on. I don't think the documentation specifies an integer type, but I strongly suspect that the error codes are always going to be 4 bytes, because for some time, nearly all Fortran implementations that use IEEE types have used 32 bit integers as the default. I think that some C wrappers may technically allow you to change the return code size at build-time (or use a system/compiler default); you may want to provide a similar option for your Java bindings.

Comment: The BLAS/LAPACK routines are defined in C by CBLAS and LAPACKE as float/double. That's the official C API that deprecates the CLAPACK translation. As to your other points, that's why I've explicitly asked for sizes **in practice**.

Comment: My point is that you should code your bindings according to the specification of the library that you're working with, not the system that it's on. You also didn't specify whether you are interfacing with CBLAS/LAPACKE, or to Fortran 77 code (which often used explicit byte counts), or whether you are also trying to allow for extended-precision on some machines. Regardless, the float/double of C are going to be IEEE single/double precision on virtually all modern systems, though integer sizes do change. (Unlike in your table above, float is still 32 bits on Linux x86_64.)

Comment: I don't know where you're going nor why any of this is relevant. If the numbers in the question are wrong, then please update them... they are only illustrative. I consider this question to be answered in the comments by @cup. I'm just waiting for him to convert his comment into an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Your original question was about getting a canonical table of Fortran and C bit sizes for different OS/architecture, and I was trying to say that OS/architecture isn't what determines Fortran sizes for your purposes (and apparently doing a bad job of that). I somehow missed the end of your conversation with cup. If you plan to write some short Fortran code using ISO_C_BINDING to figure out the mapping, that makes sense.